# Good way to catch exception in one method among several classes

Tags: ruby, exception

Currently I have several classes, each of which deals with different sites. They act like the same type, in the sense that they all have `crawl_item()` method.

```
class CrawlA
  def crawl_item
    ...
    A.create()
  end
end

class CrawlB
  def crawl_item
    B.create()
  end
end
```

Now I want to catch one model validation exception when calling any of these `crawl_item methods`, and perform the same rescue action. What would be a good way to implement this?

Comment: I guess we can assume that the methods `crawl_item` are different in each class, aren't they?

Comment: @tokland yes they do crawl but the implementations are quite different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep it DRY you can write a wrapper using the classical mix-in structure (module + class include):

```
module CrawlValidator
  def with_validations
    begin
      yield
    rescue => exc
      ...
    end
  end
end

class CrawlA
  include CrawlValidator

  def crawl_item
    with_validations { A.create }
  end
end
```